# Can't initialize PWM on dsPIC33F

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic, pwm, xc16

I'm probably just having a can't-see-the-forest-for-the-trees moment with one of these registers, but I can't get the PWM working on the [dsPIC33FJ32MC102](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70000652f.pdf) microcontroller (warning: big PDF) I'm playing around with. I've followed both the datasheet and further [application note](http://www.ee.up.ac.za/main/_media/en/undergrad/subjects/esp300/pwm_70187d.pdf) (warning: another PDF) and even code samples and I can't see what I'm doing wrong, though on my testbench I'm getting Vcc on the high output and Ground on the low output. I've tied the fault pins both to Vcc and disabled the register keycode so my changes should see some effect. What am I doing wrong?

```
#define FOSC    (3686400ULL)
#define FCY     (FOSC/2)

#include <xc.h>
#include <libpic30.h>

...

#pragma config PWMPIN = ON              // Motor Control PWM Module Pin Mode bit (PWM module pins controlled by PORT register at device Reset)
#pragma config PWMLOCK = OFF             

...

void main(void){

...

//setup PWM

//Clear faults
IFS3bits.PWM1IF     = 0;
IFS3bits.FLTA1IF    = 0;
IFS4bits.FLTB1IF    = 0;

//Setup dead times
P1DTCON1bits.DTAPS  = 0b00; //Dead time tick is 1 TCY
P1DTCON1bits.DTBPS  = 0b00;
P1DTCON1bits.DTA    = 10;    //Dead time is 10TCY ~= 3uS
P1DTCON1bits.DTB    = 10;
P1DTCON2bits.DTS1A  = 0;    //Active and Inactive transition dead times
P1DTCON2bits.DTS2A  = 0;    //0 takes A dead time
P1DTCON2bits.DTS3A  = 0;    //1 takes B dead time
P1DTCON2bits.DTS1I  = 1;
P1DTCON2bits.DTS2I  = 1;
P1DTCON2bits.DTS3I  = 1;

P1TCONbits.PTOPS    = 0b0000; //1 CPU tick = 1 PWM tick
P1TCONbits.PTCKPS   = 0b00;
P1TCONbits.PTMOD    = 0b00;
P1TCONbits.PTSIDL   = 0;      //Run when CPU idles

// no longer necessary since I disabled register write lock:
//    __builtin_write_PWMSFR(&P1FLTACON,0x0000,&PWM1KEY);
//    __builtin_write_PWMSFR(&P1FLTBCON,0x0000,&PWM1KEY);
//    __builtin_write_PWMSFR(&PWM1CON1 ,0x0077,&PWM1KEY);

PWM1CON1 = 0x0077;    //Enable all 3 channels
P1FLTACON = 0x0000;   //Disable faults
P1FLTBCON = 0x0000;

//Setup Wave freq/duty
//Fosc = 7.3728 MHz -> Fcy = 3.6864MHz
//Desire a PWM of 20250Hz (smaller scalar error than 20kHz)
//P1TPER = [Fcy/(Fpwm*Scalar)] - 1
//Therefore P1TPER = [3.6864M/(20250*1)] - 1 = 181;
P1TPER              = 181;
P1DC1               = 0x7FFF;   // 0x7FFF for 50%
P1DC2               = 0x7FFF;
P1DC3               = 0x7FFF;

P1OVDCON            = 0x3F00;   //Disable override; override disables PWM
PWM1CON2            = 0x0000;    
P1TCONbits.PTEN     = 1;        //Turn on

...

while(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have set up the timer to count from 0 to 181 (P1TPER) and then reset and repeat.  But you have set the duty cycle registers to 0x7FFF, which is greater than 181.  So I believe the duty cycle value will never be less than the timer value and therefore the output will never change.  Try setting the duty cycle registers to 181/2 = 90 to get a duty cycle of 50%.

Comment: This was almost correct so I'll give you the answer and points anyways. It made me try a low value and I got PWM at the 'wrong' duty cycle. It got me to look at the datasheet again and it corrected my wrong impression that duty cycle was arbitrary between 0 and 65535; it's not, it's between 0 - 2*P1TPER. It works now. Thanks!